# Cant boot from windows 8 after installing Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: boot, windows-8

i installed Ubuntu 13.04 as a dual boot on my samsung series 5 (NP353U4C) which came with windows 8 pre-installed. The problem is that i can't boot from windows 8 (loader) any longer, it just give me an error. I'm new to linux and i really need help to get the two working together urgently please.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per the [help/on-topic]. These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get into your linux then you can install boot-repair in your linux machine.

Open your terminal and type:

> sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

Press Enter and then the following command:

> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

Most Probably this can solve your issue

No warranty: boot-repair modifies also uefi entries and so on if it works you will be happy, if not, you may be left with bigger problems than before.